# How do I spot 'Access granted' being printed 3 times if password is correct?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, loops, input

How do I go about stopping 'Access granted' being printed when password is correctly input? Access granted get printed three times when 'swordfish' is entered

[image: enter link description here]

```
print ('The Database is password protected') # Says the Data base is password protected
print ('please enter password') #say please enter password

password = ('swordfish')
swordfish = 3

password = input()
if password == 'swordfish':

    print ('Access granted.')

else:

 if password != ('swordfish'):


    print ('wrong password.')

    print ('two attempts remain')

 else:
    password = input()

if password == 'swordfish':
    print ('Access granted.')
else:
    password = input()
if password == 'swordfish':
     print ('Access granted.')
else:
    print ('wrong password.')
    print ('one attempt remain')

    password = input()
    if password == 'swordfish':

if password != ('swordfish'):

     print ('You have been blocked from the database')
```

Comment: You need to check what your else statements are doing. If the password is correct you do one thing, otherwise you end the else (hence the ‘else’). Everything you do should be in that ‘else’. You end the else and check again, that’s why you’re seeing more ‘access granted’ being printed. Just go through your code line by line.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to stop it from being printed and clean up your code then use a loop:

Edit: This is a perfect time to use the `for-else` block of code. In this example, the `else` clause will only run when the full `for-loop` has been exhausted i.e it wont run 'You have been blocked from the database' in the event that the correct password was entered (because then the `break` statement has executed)

```
password = 'swordfish'

print('The Database is password protected')

for attempts in range(2, -1, -1):
    if input('Please enter password') == password:
        print('Access granted.')
        break
    else:
        print('Wrong password.')
        print('%s attempts remain' % attempts)
else:
    print('You have been blocked from the database')
```

Comment: Yeah, except you don't use the variable 'password' in this example. So: if input('Please enter password') == password

Answer (score 0):

```
print ('The Database is password protected')
print ('please enter password') 

password = "swordfish"

for i in range(3):
    attempt = input("Enter the password: ")
    if attempt == password:
        print("Access Granted")
        break
    else:
        print("Wrong password")
        print(2 - i, "attempt(s) reamin")

    if i == 2:
        print("You have been blocked from the database")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could **try** a **for-loop** :)

```
for e in range(3):
    a=input()
    if a=="swordfish":
        print("Access Granted")
        break
    else:
        print("Wrong Password. You have "+str(3-(e+1))+" attempts left")
```